# PHP not searching include path

Tags: php

I feel like an idiot, but I can't figure out what's wrong and every solution that I have tried (listed below) has failed.

Problem:

This doesn't work:

```
$settings = file_get_contents('settings'); \\ should search current directory
```

Where is this file Located?

```
/apps/foxyman/model/settings
```

What I have tried:

1. Changing the include_path directive in `php.ini` to:

   *.:/apps/foxyman*

   And then **restarting Apache**. And yes, I did run `phpinfo();` and verify that it was set.
2. Changing the doc_root directive to the same thing in `php.ini` and **restarting Apache.**
3. Changing the document root setting in the right httpd.conf file to: `DocumentRoot "/apps/foxyman"`
4. `$settings = file_get_contents('model/settings'); // should search include_path`

And none of this works.

Yes, I know there are potentially other solutions that involve me setting the include path in every file, but I don't want to do that - I want to solve it once and not think about it again.

To me, and maybe I'm just an idiot (which you should feel free to let me know by telling me to go kill myself in the comments), but it seems ridiculous that php can't find the file in the the current directory AND doesn't seem to be searching the include path that I set. And before you ask, yes, the file does exists.

One more thing, here is the output for the following methods:

```
echo getcwd();
echo get_include_path();
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

/apps/foxyman/model
.:/apps/foxyman
/apps/foxyman
```

Comment: What about directory access privileges? I mean, is `/model` _and_ its contents accessible to PHP (= web server)?

Comment: file_get_contents() doesn't use include_path by default, you have to pass it true as a second argument.

Comment: Also, try echoing getcwd() to see if it's actually what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) does **not** use include path! If you want it to use the include path pass `true` in the second argument.

```
$settings = file_get_contents('settings', true);
```